# How to access updated state within a loop react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to delay an action based on a state variable. In the below code `performOperation` is triggered by onBlur on an input and addNewRowItem by a click on a button. Inside `SomeComponent` the user can update the value on the input and then clicks the add another. As a result both the onBlur and onClick are triggered.

I believe I can solve this by waiting for the isSaving state variable to be updated to false. The issue is that inside the while loop of the `addNewRowItem` the state variable is always true even though I can log it as false from the useEffect. How I can I get the most up to date context variable whilst in the while loop?

```
const MyComponent = (): ReactElement => {
  const { isSaving, setIsSaving } = useProject();

  const performOperation = async (
    data: { someData: string}
  ): Promise<void> => {
    // Do some operation and then set state
    setIsSaving(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions
    console.log(`Log isSaving ${isSaving}`);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [isSaving]);

  async function sleep(time: number) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    return new Promise((resolve, _) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
  }

  const addNewRowItem = async () => {
    while (isSaving) {
      console.log(isSaving);
      console.log("looping");
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
      await sleep(500);
    }
    console.log("finished looping");
  };
  return (
      <SomeComponent
        performOperation={performOperation}
        addNewRowItem={addNewRowItem}
      />
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: State values are constant throughout the lifecycle of a given render. You'll need to utilize the render cycle for your loop if you need to make it dependent on state, ie use useEffect with relevant cleanup, or pass a callback to the setState call which implements the loop.

Comment: Solution depends on what operation you need to so in your two callbacks. The way you have it set up won't work. One solution would be to add new state into addNewRowItem and check for it in the effect that checks for is loading and move the add row logic there. But that is really ugly soluution.